# Where can be found details about the domains Icebergs and Snow?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities, domains

*Frostburn* lists on Table 2–5: Deities of the Frostfell (42) [Levistus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_devils_in_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Levistus) as granting his clerics access to the domain **Icebergs** and Vatun as granting his clerics access to the domain **Snow**. These domains don't appear in *Frostburn* or its errata. Are more details about these domains available elsewhere?

Comment: Also not found on the [usual](http://ftm3.altervista.org/ASMoNM/domains.html) [sources](http://imarvintpa.com/dndLive/Index_LevDom.php), which I presume you checked but worth mentioning.

Comment: @KRyan I'm never *entirely* sure of the line between *self-answering* and *disclosing my research* so I figured I'd omit having checked the usual sources in case someone wanted to include that in an answer. Honestly, I suspect neither domain exists, but I'm hoping one of *Frostburn*'s authors might've made the domains available unofficially.

Comment: There might be enough info in *Frostburn* + *Spell Compendium* to homebrew those domains, but almost exactly like [R.O.U.S.'s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOv5ZjAOpC8), I don't think they exist.

Comment: @Chemus I'm pretty sure the game *just doesn't need* the Snow domain (the domains Cold or Winter are enough, thanks) so it's probably the remains of a previous draft. However, I think Levistus being able to grant his clerics the Icebergs domain may have been an attempt at humor, him floating around Stygia encased in a giant iceberg and all. (But I've *nothing* to back that up except my own wryness.)

Comment: No luck on finding iceberg, but now I want to run a cleric of levistus.

Comment: From what evidence I can find it seems likely these were meant as part of the portfolio entry rather than domains. Leaves it rather thin though so I'll continue searching before I answer.

Answer (score 1):

People have asked about this occasionally for a long time (https://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?283457-D-amp-D-Frostburn-missing-domains )  It seems likely that they were either replaced by the 'cold' and 'winter' domains, or cut entirely and the entry not updated.

Anyways, if your using them for an NPC, or want to submit something to your DM to ask if you can use their is a fan suggested writeup of the domains here:

http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?525441-Missing-Domains-Icebergs-Snow-Underdark